# java removing hashmap from arraylist if it does not contain certain key sets

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, conditional-statements

Let's say I have arraylist of Hashmap,
and Hashmap contain some keys and values

```
Arraylist d = [{key1=1,key2=2},{key1=1,key3=3}]
```

I want to remove hashmap that does not contain certain key.
for example, I want to remove hashmap that does not have key2.

result should be:

```
d= [{key=1,key2=2}]
```

How do I approach this?

Comment: iterate, look inside, and keep the good ones.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Well, technically, it's: Iterate, look inside, and remove bad ones using iterator `remove()` method.

Comment: @Andreas  Exact, but I wouldnt remove while iterating, rather create a new Map, then inserting the good ones , safer and clearer.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina An option, true, but OP specifically said "I want to remove", and removing while iterating is both safe and clean. Your option would fit "I want new list without", but that's a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If source is

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list;
```

You can filter it that way:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> newList =
         list.stream().filter(m -> m.containsKey("key2")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```